# How to disable hostname verification in jetty embedded verion 9.x

Tags: jetty-9

Currently I have a Verison 9.3.x Embedded Jetty server working perfectly offering websockets communications through port 8080 and through 8443 for secure communications.
I need to disable the validation of the hostname as well as the certificates but I can not disable it.

I am using the method setTrustAll and setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(null) but the hostname verification is still activated.
sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true);
sslContextFactory.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(null);
How can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the HttpsConfiguration and setting a SecureRequestCustomizer? I was doing that when I ran into this and it drove me crazy until I realized it was my fault. So the SNI stuff is basically duplicated between the SslContextFactory and the SecureRequestCustomizer, you need to set it false in both places.